# Changing the value of signed bit after substraction

Tags: assembly, x86

i wrote this part of code in 16 bit assembler x86:

```
mov dl, F3h
mov bh, 72h
sub dl, bh
```

When I was debugging code in turbo debugger i found out, that after sub dl, bh the signed flat changed to 1, bud signed flag is set to 1 if result of operation is negative so why is signed flat set to 1 in this case, when result would be positive?

Answer (score 3):

The result of F3h - 72h is 81h. Since `sub dl, bh` is an 8-bit operation the sign bit is the eighth bit of the value (where the first bit of the value is the lowest order bit). Since the eight bit of the result 81h is set, the sign flag is set. When the unsigned value 81h is interpreted as a signed 8-bit value it becomes the negative number -7F (-127).

Comment: but why is this value interpreted as signed 8-bit value , sub dl, bh means dl=dl-bh, thus 243(F3) - 114(72) is +129(81h)

Comment: @net_man it's only viewed as a signed value if you choose to do so. The CPU provides status register information after an operation that allows either interpretation.

Comment: @net_man That what the sign flag does, it always interprets the result as a signed value. Thus as far as the signed flag is concerned your calculation is actually -0Dh - 72h = -7Fh or in decimal -13 - 114 = -127. To put it another way the sign flag is always the same as a sign bit of the result, and the sign bit is the highest order bit of the value.

Comment: The "sign bit" is just a shortcut to tell you that the last arithmetic operation resulted in an answer with the leftmost bit set. It doesn't actually know (or care) whether you, the programmer, intended the data to be signed or unsigned.